ErrorInvalidIdMalformed when Updating Microsoft Teams Meeting via Microsoft Graph API
I'm experiencing an issue while updating a Microsoft Teams meeting using the Microsoft Graph API. I receive the following error:
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: ErrorInvalidIdMalformed Message: Id is malformed. ClientRequestId: 81296c06-3cca-4ec2-b77e-301ce60c28f
I am saving meeting details in my database, including an iCalUId which is generated as a GUID. Here is how my Meeting class looks:
public Meeting()
{
    Actions = new HashSet<Action>();
    Documents = new HashSet<Document>();
    Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
    VoiceNotes = new HashSet<VoiceNote>();
    MeetingAttendees = new HashSet<MeetingAttendee>();
    MeetingProjects = new HashSet<MeetingProject>();
    Coorganizers = new HashSet<Coorganizer>();
    MeetingSuperseedHistories = new HashSet<MeetingSuperseedHistory>();
    MeetingExportHistories = new HashSet<MeetingExportHistory>();
    MeetingTopics = new HashSet<MeetingTopic>();
    iCalUId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
[Key]
public int MeetingID { set; get; }
public string Subject { set; get; }
public string iCalUId { get; set; }
      

When I attempt to update the meeting from my application dashboard, the meeting does not get updated in Microsoft Teams. Below is the code I am using to update the meeting via Microsoft Graph:
This is the code to update via graph.
 public async Task<bool> EditMeetingByAd(EditMeetingAdRequest request)
 {
     bool status = false;
     try
     {

         var eventToUpdate = await _graphClient.Users[request.OrganiserEmail].Events[request.iCalUId].Request().GetAsync();

         if (eventToUpdate != null)
         {

             eventToUpdate.Subject = request.Subject;

             .....

             eventToUpdate.Attendees = request.Attendees.Select(x =>
                  new Attendee
                  {
                      EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = x.EmailAddress, Name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) ? x.Name : null },
                      Type = x.IsOptionalAttendee ? AttendeeType.Optional : AttendeeType.Required
                  });


             var result = await _graphClient.Users[request.OrganiserEmail].Events[request.iCalUId].Request().UpdateResponseAsync(eventToUpdate);

             if (result != null)
                 status = true;
         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return status;
     }

     return status;

 }

Here is how I am saving a meeting using a service class:
                unitOfWork.Repository<Meeting>().Add(meeting);
                unitOfWork.Complete();

                CreateMeetingAdRequest adMeeting = new CreateMeetingAdRequest();
                adMeeting.OrganiserEmail = meeting.Organizer;
                adMeeting.Subject = meeting.Subject;
                adMeeting.Body = meeting.Body;
                adMeeting.Location = meeting.Location;
                adMeeting.StartTime = meeting.MeetingDate.Add(meeting.StartTime);
                adMeeting.EndTime = meeting.MeetingDate.Add(meeting.EndTime);
                adMeeting.TimeZone = "Arab Standard Time";
                adMeeting.iCalUId = meeting.iCalUId;

How to update the correct meeting id and how to get that and save as well in db so that it is synchronized between dashboard and teams, i am confused here . Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. some links i refer as here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1192280/error-code-errorinvalididmalformed-error-message-i but of no use

The error you are getting is because you are using iCalUId which is generated as a GUID instead of the actual event id when attempting to update the meeting via the API. make sure you use the event id which is returned by Microsoft Graph when the event is created for all update operations, not the iCalUId. When you create a meeting, store the event id returned by the Graph API in your database. Use this id for any future updates to the meeting. you can change your code to retrieve and use the correct event id from the database instead of iCalUId.

Thanks, but how to update vice versa, when i have to update from teams app, the date time should be saved on db. Its not persisting in db when i update meetings from teams app.
